# How to delete https and http and all after @ in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

```
https://ziyadgadjiev:tekemmen@mail.yandex.ru
http://mamed.haciyev.01:peri.94@www.ok.ru/dk
```

i need this format

```
ziyadgadjiev:tekemmen
mamed.haciyev.01:peri.94
```

what regex way to do that?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `https?://([^@]+).+$`
Replace with: `$1`

Then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>